# Vbs won't execute after function

Tags: vbscript

Am setting up a vbs that I got from the web to copy some files from one folder to another.
Everything working fine in the code, except after the “end function”.

The script does not work anymore after Line 73.The sleep code as well as the wscript.shell does not execute after that.

Can someone please help.

```
Option Explicit

Dim objShell
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
objShell.Run("""C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe""")

WScript.sleep 5000

Dim ws
Set ws=CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
ws.Run "TASKKILL.exe /F /IM vlc.exe"

WScript.sleep 8500


Dim srcFolder, trgFolder,WshShell,UserProfilePath
Set WshShell = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
UserProfilePath = WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%UserProfile%")
srcFolder = "C:\Test\"
trgFolder = UserProfilePath & "\AppData\Roaming\"

CopyFilesAndFolders srcFolder, trgFolder
WScript.Quit

Sub CopyFilesAndFolders (ByVal strSource, ByVal strDestination)
Dim ObjFSO, ObjFolder, ObjSubFolder, ObjFile, files
Dim TargetPath
Set ObjFSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
'connecting to the folder where is going to be searched
Set ObjFolder = ObjFSO.GetFolder(strSource)
TargetPath = Replace (objFolder.path & "\", strSource, strDestination,1,-1,vbTextCompare)
If Not ObjFSO.FolderExists (TargetPath) Then ObjFSO.CreateFolder (TargetPath)
Err.clear
On Error Resume Next
'Check all files in a folder
For Each objFile In ObjFolder.files
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then Exit For 'If no permission or no files in folder
    On Error goto 0
    If CheckToCopyFile (objFile.path, TargetPath & "\" & objFile.name) Then 
        objFSO.copyfile objFile.path, TargetPath & "\" & objFile.name, True
    End If
Next
'Recurse through all of the subfolders
On Error Resume Next
Err.clear
For Each objSubFolder In ObjFolder.subFolders
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then Exit For 'If no permission or no subfolder in folder
    On Error goto 0
    'For each found subfolder there will be searched for files
    CopyFilesAndFolders ObjSubFolder.Path & "\", TargetPath & ObjSubFolder.name & "\"
Next
Set ObjFile = Nothing
Set ObjSubFolder = Nothing
Set ObjFolder = Nothing
Set ObjFSO = Nothing
End Sub

Sub CopyFilesAndFolders (ByVal strSource, ByVal strDestination)
    Dim ObjFSO, ObjFolder, ObjSubFolder, ObjFile, files
    Dim TargetPath
    Set ObjFSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    'connecting to the folder where is going to be searched
    Set ObjFolder = ObjFSO.GetFolder(strSource)
    TargetPath = Replace (objFolder.path & "\", strSource, strDestination,1,-1,vbTextCompare)
    If Not ObjFSO.FolderExists (TargetPath) Then ObjFSO.CreateFolder (TargetPath)
    Err.clear
    On Error Resume Next
    'Check all files in a folder
    For Each objFile In ObjFolder.files
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then Exit For 'If no permission or no files in folder
        On Error goto 0
        If CheckToCopyFile (objFile.path, TargetPath & "\" & objFile.name) Then 
            objFSO.copyfile objFile.path, TargetPath & "\" & objFile.name, True
        End If
    Next
    'Recurse through all of the subfolders
    On Error Resume Next
    Err.clear
    For Each objSubFolder In ObjFolder.subFolders
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then Exit For 'If no permission or no subfolder in folder
        On Error goto 0
        'For each found subfolder there will be searched for files
        CopyFilesAndFolders ObjSubFolder.Path & "\", TargetPath & ObjSubFolder.name & "\"
    Next
    Set ObjFile = Nothing
    Set ObjSubFolder = Nothing
    Set ObjFolder = Nothing
    Set ObjFSO = Nothing
End Sub

Function CheckToCopyFile (ByVal strSourceFilePath, ByVal strDestFilePath)
    Dim oFSO, oFile, SourceFileModTime, DestFileModTime
    CheckToCopyFile = True
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    If Not oFSO.FileExists (strDestFilePath) Then Exit Function
    Set oFile = oFSO.GetFile (strSourceFilePath)
    SourceFileModTime = oFile.DateLastModified
    Set oFile = Nothing
    Set oFile = oFSO.GetFile (strDestFilePath)
    DestFileModTime = oFile.DateLastModified
    Set oFile = Nothing
    If SourceFileModTime =< DestFileModTime Then CheckToCopyFile = False
    Set oFSO = Nothing
    End Function

WScript.sleep 8000

Dim objShell1
Set objShell1 = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
objShell1.Run("""C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe""")
```

Comment: Edit your post and use tags for code formatting.

Comment: Hi Tom.Necessary has been done.

Comment: Your script never calls the sub or the function. It just sleeps for 8 seconds, opens a shell, and launches vlc. Is there more to it than that? How are you determining that it doesn't run after that line? Is there an error? Unexpected behavior? Also can you toss a comment on that line so we know where you are talking about for sure.

Comment: Hi JNevill, Sorry, i did not put my full code.I've updte my post.In fact there is no error after line 73.The code run but the vlc.exe will not open.

Answer (score 1):

At line 23 you have `WScript.Quit`.
You do all the things at the beginning, taskkill, copy file and folders, and after that you close the script. If you want to run VLC, place the `objShell1.Run("""C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe""")` before line 23.
Something like:

```
Dim srcFolder, trgFolder,WshShell,UserProfilePath
Set WshShell = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
UserProfilePath = WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%UserProfile%")
srcFolder = "C:\Test\"
trgFolder = UserProfilePath & "\AppData\Roaming\"

CopyFilesAndFolders srcFolder, trgFolder

WScript.sleep 8000

Dim objShell1
Set objShell1 = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
objShell1.Run("""C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe""")
WScript.Quit
```

Comment: Hi Alex Marin, thanks for the code.Its working properly now.